# Using statement still causes Code analysis issues on 2 disposable objects

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
 Using ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim st As New GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, True)

    '... some code

    Return buffer
 End Using
```

And this:

```
dim As New MemoryStream
 using st As New GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, True)

    '... some code

    Return buffer
 End Using
```

I had some legacy code which called Dispose() and Close() manually on the stream objects - this was causing CA2202 code analysis warnings about possible multiple calls to Dispose().  So I added **using** statements for both memory stream and gzipstream and the error didn't go away!?

If I used it on either the memorystream or gzipstream objects then the error then went away.  Was is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason may be, because the `GZipStream` is disposing of the underlying stream when its own `Dispose` method is called. Therefore, I'd recommend keeping the `Using` statement for the `GZipStream` only. At least, this is the behavior of most built-in stream wrappers in the .NET framework. For instance `BufferedStream` will close the underlying stream object when `Close()`/`Dispose()` is invoked (as per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx) documentation, behavior is explained in a comment in the code sample)

Comment: No, the error exists when using BOTH and goes away when only 1 using statement is used!

Comment: @jaffa, see the edit, I revisited the answer.

Comment: I thought this might be happening, thanks.